# Javascript canvas not showing

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

can you help me understand why these two javascript files are in conflict with one another? If I have both enabled only the latter canvas appears correctly, whilst particles.js doesn't work at all:

```
<canvas id="canvas_particles"></canvas>
<script src="https://vtxfactory.org/main/js/particles.js"></script>

<canvas id="evo" style="position: absolute;"></canvas>
<script src="https://vtxfactory.org/main/js/evo.js"></script>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A couple things are going on here. First, the `particles.js` only shows up on a canvas with a dark background. Second, the canvases conflict with each other. Particles throws this error message:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: canvas is not defined
    at onmousemove (particles.js:9)
```

it apparently doesn't know which canvas to attach the event listener to.

Third, you should remove the inline style on the evo canvas, so it's not `position: absolute`.

```css
#canvas_particles{
   background: #666;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas_particles"></canvas>
<script src="https://vtxfactory.org/main/js/particles.js"></script>

<!--<canvas id="evo"></canvas>
<script src="https://vtxfactory.org/main/js/evo.js"></script>-->
```